# Azure Machine Learning Endpoint LLM Live Inference (Streaming) to Update Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-openai

I have developed an application that utilizes an Azure Machine Learning Endpoint. The output of this endpoint includes an answer generated by a large language model (LLM) which is handled through the Azure OpenAI endpoint.

For user interaction, I have a bot framework solution in place. When the bot receives a user's message, it sends a request to the Machine Learning endpoint.

However, I've noticed that the response time can vary depending on the throughput of the LLM. To improve this, I'm considering implementing live inference for these models.

Is it feasible to implement live inference on the Machine Learning Endpoint side?

Additionally, in the bot framework documentation, I've come across `Context.UpdateActivityAsync`. Does this have any relevance to my situation on the BotFramework side?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: For details regarding endpoint inferencing in Azure ML you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2).

Answer (score 1):

As the requirement is for streaming LLM deployment, you can create a streaming enabled flow in Azure ML Prompt Flow and deploy it has endpoint.
For more details regarding streaming endpoint and examples, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/prompt-flow/how-to-enable-streaming-mode?view=azureml-api-2).

To enhance response time, you can consider these approaches:

1. Scale out the Azure ML Endpoint by increasing instances or nodes in your deployment configuration, allowing parallel request handling and faster response times.
2. Fine-tune the large language model for your use case, which may lead to reduced response time.